# If $T:V\to W$ is continuous at a point of $V$, prove that $T$ is continuous at the origin.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

This is the exercise 1 from the chapter Multivariate Calculus in Real Mathematical Analysis by Pugh.

It says:
Let T be a linear transformation from V to W.
Prove that (a)T is cont. at the origin.
(b)T is cont. at p.
(c)T is cont. at at least 1 point of V.
are equivalent.

I have problem proving from (c) to (a), (The others are almost trivial or by theorem can be proved immediately)

It seems that I have to "shift" the transformation to the origin from the point where it is continuous at by some epsilon or delta techniques...
Could anyone give me some suggestions?

Comment: I think this follows from the fact that if any function $f: A \to B$ is continuous at $x \in A$, then $g: A \to B$ given by $g(y) = f(y-x)$ is continuous at the origin; $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs of this aren't hard. In this case, if $T$ is continuous at $p \in V$, just define $U: V \to W$ as $U(v) = T(v-p) + T(p)$; it's evident that $T = U$ and also that $U$ is continuous at the origin (by my previous remark and the fact that $T(p)$ is constant.

Comment: Why is $T(p)$ constant?

Comment: Because in my view... U is actually the same as T and I didn't do anything.

Comment: $T(p)$ is constant because $p$ is a specific point, not a variable.

Comment: Rephrasing: if $T$ is continuous at $p$, then write $w = T(p)$. Then $v \mapsto T(v-p)$ is continuous at the origin, and so is $v \mapsto T(v-p) + w$ (because adding a constant to a continuous map doesn't change continuity). But this last map is just $T$ itself, so $T$ is continuous at the origin.